# Distance to collision normal in MoveIt!

Tags: ros, moveit, collision-detection

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

When checking for collision in MoveIt! using CollisionResult, one can get the distance to the nearest collision. Is it possible to also have the normal vector along that distance? Basically, I'm trying to get as much collision information as possible before it happens, so direction in addition to proximity would be very useful.

Thanks,
JML

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/95136/distance-to-collision-normal-in-moveit!/) by [JML](https://answers.ros.org/users/4457/jml/) on ROS Answers with karma: 26 on 2013-10-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

unfortunately the collision checking used in moveit does not currently provide the information desired. this information is included in fcl so it could be provided. could you open a bug for this?

https://github.com/ros-planning/moveit_core/issues?state=open
https://github.com/flexible-collision-library/fcl?source=cc

---

Originally posted by [isucan](https://answers.ros.org/users/1805/isucan/) with karma: 1055 on 2013-10-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0